# another transaction already in progress

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am using app engine launcher in windows and for some reason the last time i deployed my app, the transaction wouldn't finish, and now every time i try to deploy i get the error

> another transaction by user is already in progress for app: s~ myapp, version 1

i have tried doing appcfg.py rollback, which brings up a python window, which then closes again almost immediately (i think it says error but it closes so fast i cant tell for sure)

i have tried doing appcfg.py rollback C:\ my\apps\directory\path - which leads to the same as above

i have tried doing C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine appcfg.py rollback c:\my\app\path but windows then tells me it cant find C:\ program

and now im stuck for things to try?

Comment: run the rollback command from a command prompt (windows key + r then type "cmd") then you can see the problem as the window won't vanish

Comment: thanks for that, it is telling me that my C:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\my\app isnt a directory but that is definitely the path to my apps files. i have a feeling i am doing something stupid.

Comment: you may have to surround the path in quotes. Try moving your app directory to c:\myapp and pointing the appcfg to there instead, as a cheap hack.

Comment: putting it in quotes worked, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`appcfg.py rollback C:\path\to\my\app` is the required command.

If you are using Java, the rollback command is same as above, but the path to the application should be to the application's `target` directory. Otherwise, rollback will fail.