# Google App Engine - One module doesn't deploy

Tags: python, google-app-engine, deployment

I'm deploying my Python app on GAE using the command line interface, which has always worked without problems. Since yesterday, one of the modules is getting stuck on "Scanning 500 files" and in the end throws following error:

```
Another transaction by user jong.vincent is already in progress for app: s~replimeapp, version: uno. That user can undo the transaction with "appcfg rollback".
```

However when I rollback updates for this app, the error is still thrown on the next deployment. No clue what I can do to resolve this. There is another module which refers to the same files, which has no problem deploying. No clue what I can do to get rid of this. Help please!

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15029252/another-transaction-already-in-progress

Comment: The rollback actually works and confirms that the update has been rolled back. I can also deploy any other module. Just not this one specific one, which keeps giving this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the name of the module and then it worked. Very strange, but at least the problem is solved.